# ORA-00936: missing expression (Name of employees who work for more than 2 properties)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure what expression I am missing,

[image]

```
select first_name from employee
where Employee_ID in
(select Employee_ID from service
where Property_ID having count(*)>2);
```

Comment: select Employee_ID from service group by Property_ID having count(*)>2

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  Your query is missing a `GROUP BY`, but the resulting query is rather non-sensical and still should not work.

Comment: Two GROUP BY missing...

Comment: You need to GROUP if you wants to count

Comment: please REMOVE the image of code you posted. it does nothing useful at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, you are trying to write:

```
select e.first_name
from employee e
group by e.Employee_ID, e.first_name
having count(distinct Property_ID) > 2;
```

You don't explain how the data is structured, but you might be able to use `having count(*) > 2`.